# Selenium cant find element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I trying to get the specific element (Minimum Amount) with selenium but its returns empty

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get('https://www.huobi.com/en-us/trade-rules/exchange')
time.sleep(5)
name = browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.dt-wrap+ .exchange-item span:nth-child(4)')
print(name.text) # Return Empty
```

how can do it with selenium or beautifulsoap?

Answer (score 1):

Data is also populating from external source via API. So you can easily pull all the required data whatever you need using only `requests` module.

**Example:**

```
import requests
api_url = 'https://www.huobi.com/-/x/pro/v2/beta/common/symbols?r=mhzzzd&x-b3-traceid=6c1acdfbf0a19d63cc05c62de990a55c'  
req = requests.get(api_url).json()

for item in req['data']:
    print(item['display_name'])
```

**Output:**

```
REN/HUSD
NKN/HT
BRWL/USDT
NSURE/BTC
ITC/USDT
SPA/USDT
CTC/USDT
EVX/BTC
EUL/USDT
USTC/USDT
SUKU/USDT
KAN/BTC
NFT/USDC
LOOKS/USDT
IOI/USDT
DORA/USDT
BAT/USDT
QSP/ETH
WXT/USDT
RING/ETH
NEAR/ETH
SWFTC/BTC
LINK/HUSD
RUFF/USDT
EFI/USDT
DIO/USDT
AVAX/USDC
GSC/ETH
RAD/BTC
INSUR/USDT
NODL/USDT
H2O/USDT
BTC/HUSD
FIRO/ETH
KCASH/BTC
XPNT/USDT
STPT/BTC
XCN/USDT
ETC/BTC
OCN/ETH
BTC/EUR
MAN/BTC
OP/USDC
OXT/BTC
DASH/USDT
KSM/USDT
SD/USDT
YGG/BTC
```

... so on

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS_SELECTOR is wrong. Maybe do it with a list and take the element you want?

Something like:

```
exchange_items: list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="exchange-item"]')
target = exchange_items[3]
print(target.text)
```

Here we take all items and choose the 4.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case use `.get_attribute('innerText')` or `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` to get your goal with `selenium`:

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.exchange-item span:nth-of-type(4)').get_attribute('innerText')
```